# Determine whether the isolated singularities of $1/\sin{z}$ are removable or not removable.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have found the isolated singularities of $\sin{z}$ to be $k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  I would like to use the Riemann Principle to determine whether the the singularities are removable or not.  If $\lim_{z\rightarrow k\pi}\frac{z-k\pi}{\sin{z}}=0$, then the singularities are removable.

L'Hospitals rule is out of the question because we haven't learned it yet.  I thought about looking at the power series of $\sin{z}$ in order to find the limit but I can't seem to get anywhere with that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Change variable $w=z-k\pi$. Then use that $\sin(w+k\pi)=\sin(w)\cos(k\pi)+\cos(w)\sin(k\pi)=$$\sin(w)$$\cos(k\pi)=(-1)^{k}\sin(w)$ and that $\lim_{w\to0}\frac{\sin(w)}{w}=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why power series didn't work for you. At any $n\pi,\sin n\pi = 0, sin'(n\pi)=\cos n\pi =(-1)^n,$ and we don't need anything more. Why? Because this shows that near $n\pi,$ $\sin z = (-1)^n(z-n\pi)+O(|z-n\pi|^2).$ Thus $\lim_{z\to n\pi}(z-n\pi)/sin z = (-1)^n.$

Comment: I expanded my power series about zero without thinking.